# Iphone focus on input, textarea field issue using bootstrap modal

Tags: ios, css, iphone, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem. In my project I have an issue with focus on input using iphone device. The problem is that when I'm clicking on the input field and start typeing something, then, when I click iphone's mobile keyboard button 'ready', to switch to another input field, the focus go somewhere to unknown direction. So after that happen, I'm not able to scroll the modal window, instead of that, the body element scrolls, but modal window stay just as fixed element. Any adviceses would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When your app loses focus, the **blur** event will be triggered. Blur is basically the opposite of **focus**. When this event gets triggered you can focus the form again by doing the following:

1. Make sure you get the **input** elements from the form.

> let $inputElements = $('#modalDialog').find('input');

2. Add the *blur* event listener.
3. Inside your event listener force focus to your modal.

> ```
> $inputElement.on('blur', function() { 
>     let $modal = $('#modalDialog');
>     $modal.focus();  
> });
> ```

Just need to see what the correct id for your modal is and that input elements are indeed **input** elements and not **select** or any other tag that might apply.